# How to get count of elements in document array - MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following MongoDB collection (JSON):

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("570185458351bbac27bc9a20"),
    "email" : "test@gmail.com",
    "applicants" : [
            {
                    "id" : "570724e4ae4f8a5026156999",
                    "email" : "a@gmail.com",
            },
            {
                    "id" : "570724e4ae4f8a5026156333",
                    "email" : "a2@gmail.com",
            },
            {
                    "id" : "570724e4ae4f8a5026156111",
                    "email" : "a3@gmail.com",
            },
            {
                    "id" : "570724e4ae4f8a5026156222",
                    "email" : "a4@gmail.com",
            }
    ],
}, 
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("570185458351bbac27bc9a20"),
    "email" : "test@gmail.com",
    "applicants" : [
            {
                    "id" : "570724e4ae4f8a5026156555",
                    "email" : "a@gmail.com",
            },
            {
                    "id" : "570724e4ae4f8a5026156666",
                    "email" : "a2@gmail.com",
            },
    ],
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("570185458351bbac27bc9a20"),
    "email" : "test2@gmail.com",
    "applicants" : [
            {
                    "id" : "570724e4ae4f8a5026156555",
                    "email" : "a@gmail.com",
            },
            {
                    "id" : "570724e4ae4f8a5026156666",
                    "email" : "a2@gmail.com",
            },
    ],
 }
```

I would like to get the count of the elements in all arrays of the of the document where the email = test@gmail.com. How can I go about getting that count?

I am using the following to get the number of documents with email test@gmail.com using this:

```
   collection.count({"email" : tmpEmail},    function (err, count) {
      res.json(count);
      console.log("Number: " + count);
    });
```

How can I go ahead and count the number of elements in all applicant arrays for the documents where the email is test@gmail.com? The could for the example above would be: 6.

### EDIT:

As per one of the answers I modified my query to the following:

Answer 1:

```
collection.aggregate(
        {$match: {"email": req.user.username, "status" : "true"}},
        {$unwind: "$applicants"},
        {$group: {_id:null, count: {$sum :1}},  function (err, count) {
            res.json(count);
            console.log("Number of New Applicants: " + count);
            }
        });
```

Answer 2:

```
collection.aggregate(
        [{$match:{"email" : req.user.username, "status" : "true"}}, 
         {$project:{_id:0, email:1, totalApplicants:{$size:"$applicants"}}},  
         {$group:{_id:"$employer", count:{$sum:"$totalApplicants"}}}],
         function (err, count){
             res.json(count);
             console.log("Number of New Applicants: " + count);
         });
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use an aggregate query instead:

```
collection.aggregate(
    [{$match: {"email": req.user.username, "status" : "true"}},
    {$unwind: "$applicants"},
    {$group: {_id:null, count: {$sum :1}}}],  function (err, result) {
        console.log(result);
        console.log("Number of New Applicants: " + result[0].count);
        if(result.length > 0)
            res.json(result[0]);
        else
            res.json({count:0});
        }
    });
```

This will result you in one document where count will have your required result

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, I have modified the query slightly but everytime it gets called, I get a 500 error in node. I have added the updated query to my post. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: see my edit. If still it doesn't work, tell me the output of result. result will be always an array and you might have to check if result length is greater than 0

Comment: The error I get with the modified query is "TypeError: collection.aggregate is not a function". From what I read online about this it usually has to o with the aggregate function not having a callback but in this case it does, the function(err,result) correct?  I also needed to add an extra } after {$sum :1}

Answer (score 2):

This may require to write a aggregation since you need to count the size of applicants array grouped by email:

Here is the equivalent mongodb query that returns the expected email with count:

```
db.yourCollection.aggregate(

  [{$match:{"email" : "test@gmail.com"}}, 

  {$project:{_id:0, email:1,totalEmails:{$size:"$applicants"}}},  

  {$group:{_id:"$email", count:{$sum:"$totalEmails"}}}])
```

This returns `{ "_id" : "test@gmail.com", "count" : 6 }`

You may need to change this according to your code.

Comment: I have tried this and I can't seem to get it working, I needed to modify the query a bit but still no luck. I have updated my original post with the query I tried.